# React Router Navigate pathing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to understand better how the useNavigate works as I'm not really understanding the pattern.

This is my Routes

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/questionaire" element={<Questionaire />} />
        <Route path="questionaire/1" element={<Question1 />} />
        <Route path="questionaire/2" element={<Question1 />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

On the Questionaire page I use **navigate("1")** and it goes into the path **"/questionaire/1"** -
Nice!

Now on question1 I want to go into **"/questionaire/2"**:

- **navigate("2")** - leads me into **/questionaire/1/2**
- **navigate("/2")** - leads me into **/2**
- **navigate("questionare/2")** - leads me into **/questionaire/1/questionaire/2**

How do I make an increment so every question just adds ++
How do I go from questionaire/5 into questionaire/2 using navigate?

I'm using navigate in buttons, should I use LINK? with a button nested in it? Why?

EDIT: doesn't necessarily have to increment the value, but just replace the current number with the one I want - ex question/1 to question/2 or from question/5 to question/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking about is the fundamental difference between absolute and relative routing. In `react-router-dom@6` the ***only*** thing that differentiates relative links and routes from absolute links and routes is the leading `"/"` character.

- Absolute links and routes:

  - Begin with a leading `"/"` character, i.e. `"/root/segment1/segment2"`
  - Replace the entire path

    ```
    // "/root/segment1"
    navigate("/root/otherPath");
    // "/root/otherPage"
    ```
- Relative links and routes:

  - Do not begin with a leading `"/"` character, i.e. `"segment2"`
  - Append to the current path

    ```
    // "/root/segment1"
    navigate("otherPath");
    // "/root/segment1/otherPage"
    ```

    ...

    ```
    // "/root/segment1"
    navigate("../otherPath");
    // "/root/otherPage"
    ```

I suggest the following route refactor:

- All sibling routes can be wrapped and rendered by a single `Routes` component.
- Use layout and index routes to help manage/organize nested routes.

Code

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
    <Route path="/questionaire">
      <Route index element={<Questionaire />} /> // "/questionaire"
      <Route path="1" element={<Question1 />} /> // "/questionaire/1"
      <Route path="2" element={<Question2 />} /> // "/questionaire/2"
      ...
      <Route path="<N>" element={<QuestionN />} /> // "/questionaire/<N>"
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Use absolute paths to navigate from to the parent path or from question to question:

```
navigate("/questionaire");   // to parent
navigate("/questionaire/1"); // to question #
navigate("/questionaire/2");
navigate("/questionaire/N");
```

Use relative paths from the parent layout route on `path="/questionaire"`:

```
navigate("..");   // to parent
navigate("../1"); // to question #
navigate("../2");
navigate("../N");
```

Notice here that we can use `".."` to navigate relatively to the parent route. This is useful to navigate along sibling components.

Comment: Thank you, this really enlighten me on my issue!

Answer (score 1):

as i know. (i am noob)

> On the Questionaire page I use navigate("1") and it goes into the path "/questionaire/1" - Nice! Now on question1 I want to go into "/questionaire/2": navigate("2") - leads me into /questionaire/1/2

When you use just a number or string, useNav just adding it with / after current path. If you instead of number 2 write 'hi' it navigate you to /hi.

> navigate("/2") - leads me into /2.

Its because you wrote absolute path, if before your string in useNav you will add "/", then its meaning "yourhost"+"your string".
example:
Your host is localhost:3000. If you entered '/test' in useNav it will be localhost:3000/test. Or you want add this "/test/2/3" - then it will be localhost:3000/test/2/3.

> navigate("questionare/2") - leads me into /questionaire/1/questionaire/2

as i said if you have just string and before it you didnt add /, then its just added after your current path.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense, I was a bit aware of what you described but my doubt really was in the second part of my question, how do I make it work as intended

Comment: glad to hear it)

Answer (score 1):

Answering you second question:

> How do I make an increment so every question just adds ++ How do I go
> from questionaire/5 into questionaire/2 using navigate?
>
> navigate("questionare/2") - leads me into
> /questionaire/1/questionaire/2

You can do this using absolute path (e.g: '/questionaire/2') or relative path (e.g: '2'), you can either do this using a Link or programmatically using a useNavigate hook.

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
const handleClick = () => {
   navigate('2')
   //or
  navigate('/questionaire/2')
}
```

Your current code is using relative path + adding entire path, which leads to duplicated path as you mentioned.